# sqlite android select col(x) where (col1 like '%key%') or (col2 like '%key%') - and x is columnt containing key

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, select

I need sql statement being something like that:

select col(x) where (col1 like '%key%') or (col2 like '%key%') or .... - and x is column containing the key (patern).

More precisely i have a table containing text columns col1, col2, col3, col4 etc.

Now I want in all those columns to find a given pattern (like). However as the result of select I would like to get column contents where the pattern has been found (in the my "statement" I've marked it as col(x).

The open question is what if two or more columns of the same statement contains the same pattern. Then for example I could get something like col(x), col(y) but it's not a must. Any other reasonable solution is welcome.

The question is how to write such a statement I need?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) to search for the column:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col1 LIKE :pattern THEN col1
            WHEN col2 LIKE :pattern THEN col2
            ...
       END AS colx
FROM MyTable
WHERE col1 LIKE :pattern OR col2 LIKE :pattern OR ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However I'm wondering about the efficiency as in fact like will be "executed" twice for each column.

Comment: And one thing more, is that possible to have only one ?, as then when using SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery I will have to add so many parameters... (ok I can do it when creating string with sql statement but i'm wondering if there is any more elegant solution)?

Comment: The CASE will be executed only for records that actually match, and the database performance depends mostly on the amount of I/O.